# How to change text size with radio button - JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am trying to update the text size of the header and paragraph information of each item in a listview. Here is the JQuery I have so far:

```
$('#rc1').prop('checked', 'true', function(){
    $(".feedContainer ul li h3").css('font-size', '1em');
    $(".feedContainer ul li p").css('font-size', '.9em');

});

$('#rc2').prop('checked', 'true', function(){
    $(".feedContainer ul li h3").css('font-size', '1.5em');
    $(".feedContainer ul li p").css('font-size', '1.4em');
    $('#header-title').html('test');

});

$('#rc3').prop('checked', 'true', function(){
    $(".feedContainer ul li h3").css('font-size', '2em');
    $(".feedContainer ul li p").css('font-size', '1.9em');

});
```

Here is the html:

```
 <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <legend>Text Size</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="rc1" id="rc1" value="off" >
        <label for="rc1">A</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rc2" id="rc2" value="off">
        <label for="rc2">A</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rc3" id="rc3" value="off">
        <label for="rc3">A</label>
 </fieldset>
```

and the CSS for the size of the letter "A" in the radio button group (also not working):

```
#rc1 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#rc2 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

#rc3 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Can someone lend me a hand with this? Thank you!

Edit: Added CSS for feedContainer:

```
.feedContainer ul li h3 {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    white-space:normal;
}
.feedContainer ul li p {
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: what is  $(".feedContainer  ? Html , CSS ? and where is the HTML CSS for .feedContainer

Answer (score 0):

the jquery .class selector selects all elements where the classname is .class try it like this see what the var is

```
 var color = $("div").css( "background-color" );
```

is .feedContainer an element ?

Comment: .feedContainer is a class

Comment: Well, even if I changed the result of the click function to say: $('#page-title').html("test"); the function still doesn't work

Comment: think it's fiddle time, can you create a JSFiddle ?

Comment: if I add this the css works   $(".feedContainer ul li").css('font-size', '35px'); outside of your functions, so your functions seemingly are not being called ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50083/discussion-between-bacon2305-and-saj)